# Function being run when bind in jquery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, click

I'm trying to bind a click event to the function below, however the entire function is currently being run when being binded in the document ready.

Is it possible to run it solely on the click event? Possibly it has something to do with the way my method is composed?

Thanks in advance

```
    $(function() {
        $("#expand-search").on("click", search.resize());
    });

    var search = {

        element: $('#search_advanced'),

        resize: function() {
            search.element.slideToggle(400, 'swing', search.buttonState());
        },
        buttonState: function() {
            if(search.element.is(':hidden')) {
                console.log('hidden');
            } else {
                console.log('visible');
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `function` (handler) instead of passing the `reference` (name) of function (handler) to [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

*Change*

```
 $("#expand-search").on("click", search.resize());
```

*To*

```
 $("#expand-search").on("click", search.resize);
```

Comment: Totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[No parenthesis](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2) to event handlers! You want to pass the function-to-be-executed, not the result from executing it. Also, you will need to move your `search` object inside the ready handler since you use selectors for its initialisation.

```
$(function() {
    var search = {
        element: $('#search_advanced'),
        resize: function() {
            search.element.slideToggle(400, 'swing', search.buttonState);
        },
        buttonState: function() {
            if(search.element.is(':hidden')) {
                console.log('hidden');
            } else {
                console.log('visible');
            }
        }
    };
    $("#expand-search").on("click", search.resize);
});
```